# 1995 Geo Tracker - Shifting Issues

Tags: clutch, shifting, manual-transmission, tracker, geo

I just put in transmission fluid and replaced the clutch cable.  I've re-adjusted it (not that I have much if a clue on what I'm doing).

It did good for a few days then I had a problem with 2nd gear and some times it grinds when putting it into 4th and reverse.  Do I need to replace the clutch or is it something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try and readjust the clutch again and see if that helps. According to the Haynes manual:

> ... there should be 1-2 milimeters of free play at the bell crank lower end.

That's not very much play.

Secondarily, I see from [this forum](http://forums.off-road.com/suzuki-geo-all/105013-tracker-clutch-adjustments.html), you might have an issue akin to one I had on my car way back when.

Check the firewall where the cable goes through. As he says his mechanic found the following:

> The hole through the firewall where the clutch cable passes was torn in 2 places, nearly an inch long allowing to firewall to flex every time the clutch pedal was pushed in. The fix was to install a plate, 1/8" thick over the broken hole, fasten it to the firewall and then put correct sized holes in the plate. It seems to be working perfectly now.

If this is not the case, I'd suggest the synchros in your transmission are going out and you'll need to look at a rebuild/replacement.

Comment: Thank you guys I readjusted the clutch its good going into gear but still the clutch isn't as tight as I'd like but for now it gets me back and forth to work (unfortunately it's a 45 minute drive lets hope nothing goes wrong in-between) the other day the cable broke and I had to free shift it not at all recommend. btw I hope I didn't cause to much damage doing that

Answer (score 3):

On top of what Paul already suggested...

It is interesting that it is 2nd, 4th, and reverse (assuming that reverse is next to 4th) since they are all on the bottom half.  Not sure what would break/wear out to cause that.

Follow the cable from to pedal to the throw out arm to check for damage.  Check the connections at the pedal and the transmission.  Have someone get in the car and press the pedal while you watch for movement/play.

grinding is caused by the clutch not releasing or the synchros.  If your clutch is failing, it will slip when fully engaged.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only having problems with 2,4,R, I'd suspect the gear linkages rather than the clutch - it sounds like it's not going fully into gear, which probably means the fore-aft linkage is loose or misaligned.

I had a similar problem on a Peugeot many years ago, it turned out in that case that the gearbox mount had broken, allowing the 'box to drop enough to pull the linkage out of alignment...