# ok still not working right 95 Geo Tracker clutch

Tags: clutch, shifting, manual-transmission, tracker, geo

IRT [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/18696/1995-geo-tracker-shifting-issues) ... At first I thought I had it good (the clutch) now it idles too high and the peddle won't come all the way back up. I can't put into first or second and I'm at a loss not sure how to actually do this (never said I was a mechanic). Does anyone have any ideas on what I can do before I take it to a shop?

Comment: High idle can indicate a vacuum leak. Check your hoses and air filter.

Answer (score 3):

Vacuum leak and sounds like you need to bleed your clutch. Bleeding the clutch is not that hard. For the vacuum leak, the main place you want to check is the actuator that should be under the battery tray. Look around for cracked lines, or lines that look older.

Now to bleed the clutch, you want to follow the lines that go under the vehicle and there will be a bleeder valve near the right side of the front differential. Have another person push down on the clutch pedal as you unscrew the valve a little bit. Don't take it all the way out, just enough to get the air out of the system. Make sure your are adding in fluid to the reservoir so no air goes back in. Close the valve after your friend pushes the clutch down. The pedal should stay all the way down to the floor. This is normal, simply pull the pedal back all the way. Repeat this process till you can feel the clutch disengaging.

Comment: You should make this a better answer by saying the steps involved in bleeding a clutch and how a vacuum leak could occur, where one might be found, and how to go about finding the vacuum leak. Short answers like these are ripe for the close hammer ...

Comment: I just added how to do it.