# Transmission 1992 geo tracker 5 speed 4 wheel drive

Tags: manual-transmission

I have a 1992 geo tracker 5 speed 4 wheel drive and it is throwing me a curve ball the transmission will go into gear but will not move I have changed the transmission fluid and looked for any thing obvious but I have found nothing I was in my pasture riding around and stoped and backed up then when I agent to pull of it wouldn’t move all it would do is click into gear any advice on it

Comment: See https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/18696/10976

Comment: Hi and welcome. It would be better if your post was written with proper sentences - starting with capitals, ending with periods, and not run-on. Makes it easier for us to read.

Comment: Your transfer case lever would not be sitting in the N position by any chance? That would definitely produce the effect you are describing (if I'm reading it correctly).